# Run rails on secure (https) and redirect non secure(http) request to secure through webricks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, webrick

I am using the below environments:

```
Server: Webrick
Rails: 3.2.6
Ruby: 1.9.3p555
```

I have added the below code in /script/rails :

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

if ENV['SSL'] == "true"
  module Rails
      class Server < ::Rack::Server
          def default_options
              super.merge({
                  :Port => 3000,
                  :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production").dup,
                  :daemonize => false,
                  :debugger => false,
                  :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                  :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                  :SSLEnable => true,
                  :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                  :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.key").read),
                  :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.crt").read),
                  :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]],
              })
          end
      end
  end
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

I have added the below line in /config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Now I have tried the below attempts:

1. Start rails on 3000

   `SSL=true rails s -e production -p 3000`

It runs rails on https://project.com but 404 error on http://project.com

2. Start rails on 443 and mentioned the same port in script:

   `rvmsudo rails s -p 443`
3. Start rails on 80 and 443 both using two different pid:

   `rvmsudo rails s -p 80 -P PID1
    rvmsudo rails s -p 443 -P PID2`

4.Finally I have tried to forward request to 3000 from 443 and 80:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

Also I have tried to run same thing with thin gem as well but results are same.

Comment: Have you considered setting up nginx, or some other tool which can do ssl-termination in stead of doing it in ruby?

Comment: No i don't wana other server.

Comment: You have only one server, but you use nginx to terminate ssl and do static asset hosting. It is much faster than any ruby-based solution, and it is very easy to solve the issues you are explaining.

Comment: Could you please answer what steps i have to change or have you did it earlier

Comment: Just an FYI regarding your `SSL requirement` statement in your bounty. I'm pretty sure that there aren't any `enterprise` applications running behind `webrick`, not without an `apache` or `nginx` frontend.

Comment: I m not sure about your region however here we did the same.

Comment: Kind of like what @PeteyT said but I'm fairly certain the rails documentation even says to not use webrick for production environment. nginx is probably the tool you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the risk of getting flamed and downvoted...

Having a **hammer** and only seeing everything as a **nail** isn't a valid plan. Sometimes when faced with a **screw** you have to find a **screwdriver**.

Webrick is the worst available option for a rails web server and should only be used if absolutely necessary. Its too simple to put thin or puma in your Gemfile and move along in a happier, thread-safier world.

In that regard here is your nine step plan to sanity.

Step 1: Stop.

Step 2: Think a bit.

Step 3: Realize best practices are there for a reason, e.g. perfect forward secrecy, load balancing to proxied rails apps, static asset serving.

Step 4: Decide to stop reinventing the wheel and take the time to learn your craft.

Step 5: Install nginx via your distribution's repos

Step 6: [Change default nginx host to serve your domain via SSL.](https://gist.github.com/nacengineer/fc05cf8121893d650d14)

Step 7: Add puma to your Gemfile, and bundle update

Step 8: [Setup puma init.d or upstart file so it persists across reboots](https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle)

Step 9: Profit

Comment: It would be better if you csn share thr steps to do so

Comment: I'm confused... you're basically talking about steps 5-8... short of doing it myself, like I did in step 6 ... step 5 is easily googleable, and step 8 is a walkthrough

Comment: This is the best answer. Dinesh, you might be missing Step 2. This setup process is quite simple!

Comment: rvmsudo rails s -p 80 -P PID1 rvmsudo rails s -p 443 -P PID2 abd I changed SSL port to 443 in script file and it work

Comment: I have started with Phussion Passenger however I do not know how to start rails now. The dfault page showing 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code in /script/rails :

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
require 'rack'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'

if ENV['SSL'] == "true"
  module Rails
      class Server < ::Rack::Server
          def default_options
              super.merge({
                  :Port => 443,
                  :environment => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production").dup,
                  :daemonize => false,
                  :debugger => false,
                  :pid => File.expand_path("tmp/pids/server.pid"),
                  :config => File.expand_path("config.ru"),
                  :SSLEnable => true,
                  :SSLVerifyClient => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
                  :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.key").read),
                  :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
                                   File.open("certs/project.crt").read),
                  :SSLCertName => [["CN", WEBrick::Utils::getservername]],
              })
          end
      end
  end
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

I have added the below line in /config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Start rails on 80 and 443 both using two different pid:

```
SSL=true rails s -p 443 -e production   
rails s -p 80 -P SERVER2 -e production
```